# MySQL ignoring query request

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

Any problems you can notice? So far to my tests, I get a HTTP 500 whenever I have the queries in. I am quite new to PHP and could get the most help as possible.

```
    <?php
require_once "dbConnect.php";
require "../www/showArticle.php";

$queryBodyCommand = "SELECT pbody FROM pages WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1";
$queryBody = mysql_query($sqlConnect, $queryBodyCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryBody)) { 
    $body = $row["pbody"];
    $title = $row["title"];
}  
mysql_free_result($queryBody);

$queryLabelCommand = "SELECT id, label FROM pages WHERE showLabel ='1' AND enabled ='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$queryLabel = mysql_query($sqlConnect, $queryLabelCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryLabel)) {
    $pid = $row["id"];
    $label = $row["label"];
    $menuList = '<a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $label . '</a><br />';
    } 
mysql_free_result($queryBody);

?>
```

This is my showArticle.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../sub/dbConnect.php');
require('../sub/functions.php');
if (!$_GET['pid']) {
    $pageid = '1';
} else {
    $pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $title; ?>
Body:
<?php echo $body; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your error log show?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite a beginner, where is the default location of the error log?

Comment: $pageid is in my index.php where the request from the $_GET['pid'] is.

Comment: @user1858233 That depends on what sort of stack you are running. Can you clarify what OS and web server you are using?

Comment: Yes the server is ran on debian OS with apache2, php5, and mysql.

Comment: require('whatever'); not require 'whatever';

Comment: Ehh still a HTTP 500 :/ Thank you though!

Comment: If you're a beginner, please **avoid** using `mysql_query` and instead spend the small amount of time to learn [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). It will save you considerable time and frustration. Better still would be to learn an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to avoid having to get hip-deep in low-level SQL. What you're doing here is terrifyingly full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and should not be exposed to the public internet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');
require('../www/showArticle.php');
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, my problem is actually the whole query situation though.

Comment: Do those commands require functions succeed?  What happens you take out all the query stuff and just load the requires?  500 error?  Are you able to echo out the values found in the required files?

Comment: When I take out the query stuff the require is all fine and dandy with PHP

Comment: I think you might have some sort of loop in your requires.  Are both pages trying to require() each other?  I see that both are trying to load dbConnect.php is there are reason for that?  Is the first file you list 'functions.php'?